# React: Index.css is not applying after added :id to url params

Tags: css, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

i am using react and had all of my pages import index.css (because i called it from index.html).
After i added /:id parameter to the url of pages it suddenly stopped getting the style from the index.css but does take it from other css files that are imported directly to the page in react.

The route looks like this now:

```
              <PrivateRoute path="/:id/whatsapper" component={Whatsapper} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
```

and before looked like:

```
              <PrivateRoute path="/whatsapper" component={Whatsapper} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
```

Was anyone facing this issue?
Why is is happenning?

Comment: can you should me how did you import or using index.css

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue,
i imported the css like :

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
```

instead of :

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.css" />
```